# recurrence relation and sigma notation

Tags: recurrence-relations

Can anyone help me and explain with sigma notation rules how does this equation solved

The problem for me that $T(i)$ and $T(i-1)$ are inside sigma notation(not i) so i am confused. Please anyone show me how is it calculated ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEx84.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

$$
\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, n>1,T(n)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}(T(i)+T(i-1)+c)\\
\forall n>2, T(n-1)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-2}(T(i)+T(i-1)+c)
$$
Now:
$$
\begin{align}
T(n)&=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}(T(i)+T(i-1)+c)\\
&=T(n-1)+T(n-2)+c+\underbrace{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-2}(T(i)+T(i-1)+c)}_{=T(n-1)}\\
&=T(n-1)+T(n-2)+c+T(n-1)\\
&=2T(n-1)+T(n-2)+c
\end{align}
$$